# Equation for Ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I'm trying to find an equation that draws an ellipse in the same vein as drawing it with the pin and string method. Basically inputting the $2$ "pin" locations and the max distance between the $2$ pins aka the string length.

From my search, the pin locations would be called foci and the distance between them would be $2\cdot c$ where
$$
c=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)
$$

and the string length would be
$$
\text{String Length} = 2b + 2c
$$

The ellipse would not have to be locked to the $x$ or $y$ axis. Long story short, I have $2$ locations (points $A$ and $B$) on a map that I need to draw an ellipse around with the distance from $A$ to $E$ (point on the ellipse) $+$ distance from $B$ to $E = \text{max range}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Are you looking for a parametric description (such as $(x, y) = (a\cos t, b\sin t)$ for an axis-oriented ellipse) or an implicit description (such as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$)? <> Either way, the starting point is the Euclidean distance formula coming from the Pythagorean theorem: $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to organise the data:

Suppose the two fixed points are $A=(a, b)$ and $B= (c, d)$.

Let the distance $AB = l$.

Let the string have length $S=l+L$

Using the Euclidean distance between a point $P=(x,y)$ and the two points $A$ and $B$ you want $$\sqrt {(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}+\sqrt {(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2}=L$$

It will take a little ingenuity to convert this to a more familiar form.